# Is there any value/ argument I can pass in php query in select so that that specific field is not considerd

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in PHP and SQL. Here I'm trying to make a filter to my home movie database-which is basically a webpage, which displays movies on my computer. There are four filters (actor, director, year, and category), and if I pass all the correct values for each field (I'm not sure is it called as column or field) in database table, it lists all the poster of corresponding movies.

But, if I want to select actor as 'All actors' (do not consider field actor while filtering), how can i do that? Is there any specific argument to pass (I tried '*' but doesn't work and kept blank '', returns all movies which field 'actor' is empty.

Here is the function I wrote:

```
function retrive_movies($actor, $director, $year, $category) {
    echo "<ul>";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `movie` WHERE `actor` = $actor AND `director` = $director AND `year` = $year `category` = $category");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if (empty($row['poster_location']) === false){
            echo "<li><img src=" . $row['poster_location'] . "><p>" . $row['movie_name'] . "</p>User rating: " . $row['user_rating'] . "</p></li>";
        }}

    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: While you are at it, please start using mysqli instead of mysql, which is deprecated since PHP 5.5. http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: Thanks for information. I will start using mysqli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
SELECT * FROM `movie` WHERE `actor` LIKE '%$actor%' AND `director` LIKE '%$director%' AND `year` LIKE '%$year%' `category` LIKE '%$category%'
```

in this query if your filter is empty it will match all records because of '%%' another way could be you make it match with itself if filter is empty.

also if `'%filter%'` does not meet your need than this query will be more appropriate.

```
SELECT * FROM `movie` WHERE `actor` = IF($actor = '', `actor`, $actor) AND `director` = IF($director = '', `director`, $director) AND `year` = IF($year = '', `year`, $year) `category` = IF($category = '', `category`, $category)
```

in case if filter argument comes empty query will match that `column/field` with itself thus match all the time.

Comment: It works..... Thanks  ɢʜʘʂʈ ʀɛɔʘɴ, You saved my day. Thanks a lot.  and the symbol "%%" was I'm searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like below,this is not tested,

```
function retrive_movies($actor='', $director='', $year='', $category='') {
echo "<ul>"; 

if($actor!= '' && $director!='' && $year!='' && $category!='') {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `movie` WHERE `actor` = $actor AND `director` = $director AND `year` = $year `category` = $category");
} else {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `movie` WHERE 1 ");
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (empty($row['poster_location']) === false){
        echo "<li><img src=" . $row['poster_location'] . "><p>" . $row['movie_name'] . "</p>User rating: " . $row['user_rating'] . "</p></li>";
    }}

echo "</ul>";
}
```